# Resize(more) CS50 pset 3 is not working correctly

Tags: c, cs50, bmp

I am completing Harvard's CS50 course and stuck with a resize(more) on pset 3.

Enlargening pictures is going ok, but when it comes to shrinking, I get files with text and a lot of question marks instead of images. It seems that everything is ok, but I can't figure out why it is not working. Thx in advance!
Here's my code:

```
// Copies a BMP file

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "bmp.h"

int resizeLarger(FILE* outptr, FILE* inptr, int n);
int resizeSmaller(FILE* outptr, FILE* inptr, int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: resize  count[-100-0|0-100] infile outfile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[2];
    char *outfile = argv[3];
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);


    // open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 2;
    }

    // open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 3;
    }

  
   
    if(n>0){
        resizeLarger(outptr,inptr,n);
    }else{
        resizeSmaller(outptr,inptr,n);
    }


    // success
    return 0;
}


int resizeLarger(FILE* outptr, FILE* inptr, int n)
{  
 // read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf,bfR;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);
    bfR = bf;
    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi,biR;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);
    biR = bi;
    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    biR.biWidth = bi.biWidth * n;
    biR.biHeight = bi.biHeight * n;
    
    int padding = (4 - (bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;
    int outPadding = (4 - (biR.biHeight * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    bfR.bfSize = 54 + ((biR.biWidth + outPadding) * abs(biR.biHeight))*sizeof(RGBTRIPLE);

    biR.biSizeImage = ((biR.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + outPadding) * abs(biR.biHeight));

    printf("%i - %i; %i\n",biR.biWidth,biR.biHeight,biR.biSizeImage);

    // write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bfR, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&biR, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // determine padding for scanlines



    // iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0, biHeight = abs(bi.biHeight); i < biHeight; i++)
    {

        for(int m=0; m<n; m++){

       

        // iterate over pixels in scanline
        for (int j = 0; j < bi.biWidth; j++)
        {
            // temporary storage
            RGBTRIPLE triple;

            // read RGB triple from infile
            fread(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, inptr);
            for(int l = 0;l<n;l++){
                // write RGB triple to outfile
                fwrite(&triple, sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), 1, outptr);
            }
           
        }


        for (int k = 0; k < outPadding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }

        if (m < n - 1)
            {
                fseek(inptr, -bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), SEEK_CUR);
            }
    }
    fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    // close infile
    fclose(inptr);

    // close outfile
    fclose(outptr);

  
      
   
    return 0;
}

int resizeSmaller(FILE* outptr, FILE* inptr, int n)
{

    int counter = abs(n);


    
     BITMAPFILEHEADER bf,bfR;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);
    bfR = bf;
    // read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi,biR;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);
    biR = bi;
    // ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 4;
    }

    biR.biWidth = bi.biWidth / counter;
    biR.biHeight = bi.biHeight / counter;

    int padding = (4-(bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE))%4)%4;
    int outPadding = (4-(biR.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE))%4)%4;

    bfR.bfSize = 54 + ((biR.biWidth + outPadding) * abs(biR.biHeight))*sizeof(RGBTRIPLE);

    biR.biSizeImage = ((biR.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + outPadding) * abs(biR.biHeight));


    fwrite(&biR,sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER),1,outptr);
    fwrite(&bfR,sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER),1,outptr);

    RGBTRIPLE triple;

    fseek(inptr, 54, SEEK_SET);
    fseek(outptr, 54, SEEK_SET);
    
    printf("%i - %i; bfSize - %i; biSizeImage - %i; counter - %i\n",biR.biWidth,biR.biHeight,bfR.bfSize,biR.biSizeImage,counter);


    for(int i =0 ; i<abs(biR.biHeight);i++){

        for(int j = 0; j<biR.biWidth;j++){

            fread(&triple,sizeof(RGBTRIPLE),1,inptr);
            fwrite(&triple,sizeof(RGBTRIPLE),1,outptr);
            fseek(inptr,sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) * (counter - 1),SEEK_CUR);
        }

        for(int j=0;j<outPadding;j++){
            fputc(0x00,outptr);
        }

        fseek(inptr,(bi.biWidth * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE) + padding)*(counter-1),SEEK_CUR);
    }

        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're reading and writing binary files, then you should open them in binary mode (e.g. `"rb"` and `"wb"`).

Comment: On a different note: If the "resize" function doesn't open the files, it should not be their responsibility to close the file. Keeping responsibilities separate makes programs and code easier to maintain.

Comment: Note that the issue about "binary mode" mentioned by someone else will not be a problem if you are running your program on a POSIX platform (e.g. Linux), because on those platforms, there is no difference between text mode and binary mode. However, this will likely be an issue on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: For some reason, writing the FILEHEADER and INFOHEADER to the output file are reversed in the `smaller()` function... May play a part in the problem...

Comment: Thx for all the advices guys. @Someprogrammerdude I am working with CS50 sandbox and tried to open files in binary, but it didn't help :(